# Авто-тесты Java: как подключиться к телефону и достать из смс код подтверждения

Tags: java, test-automation, testng

Пишу автотесты на Java + testNG. 
Для некоторых тестов, по типу регистрации, подтверждение приходит в виде 6ти значного цифрового кода в смске на телефон. Т.к. это осуществляется сторонними сервисами, то нет возможности создать универсальный тестовый код подтверждения, поэтому необходимо подключаться к телефону, из смс выдергивать код подтверждения и передавать его дальше по API или через UI.

Немного сталкивался с Appium для выполнения тестов на телефоне (работа с браузером), но никогда не приходилось лезть в смс и доставать оттуда какие-либо данные.

Просьба подсказать/дать ссылку - что почитать, изучить, с помощью чего смогу реализовать данный функционал.

Comment: Кто присылает смс?

Comment: Я в таких случаях пишу мок стороннего сервиса и не мучаюсь. Гужно конечно еще протестировать работу самого сервиса и интеграцию, это приходится делать в ручную.

Comment: смс присылает alfasms

Answer (score 1):

Узнаешь app activity и app package приложения который отвечает у тебя за смс, после определяешь элементы и используешь.

Что бы узнать app activity и app package делаешь следующие:
открываешь командную строку вбиваешь: adb shell. В момент открытия приложения на телефоне вбиваешь  dumpsys window windows | grep -E ‘mCurrentFocus’[image: здесь описано что чем является]

Для следующего шага тебе понадобиться включить appium.
Открываешь среду разработки -> cоздаешь класс, в него пихаешь код:

```
    static DesiredCapabilities caps;
static AndroidDriver<MobileElement> driver;

static void appium_option_zte() {
    caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
    caps.setCapability("deviceName", "Имя деваса");
    caps.setCapability("udid", "f9c944bf");// тут все понято
    caps.setCapability("platformName", "Android"); //платформа
    caps.setCapability("platformVersion", "7.1.1"); //версия ведра
    caps.setCapability("appPackage", "mobi.sevenwinds.askedo");
    caps.setCapability("appActivity", "mobi.sevenwinds.askedo.gui.start.splash.SplashActivity");
    caps.setCapability("noReset", "true");
    try {
        driver = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"), caps);

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        System.out.println("Ошибка отправки команды на сервер");
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
```

Если все сделал правильно при результатом компиляции будет открытие приложения.
Дальше с помощью appium или uiautomator узнаешь id интересующий тебя компонентов.
[Здесь подробно описана работа с appium для начинающего](http://www.automationtestinghub.com/appium-tutorial/)

Comment: спасибо большое за развернутый ответ!!!

Answer (score 0):

как вариант еще посоветовали использовать http://codolutions.com/relayme.html для андроида. На айфоне пересылка смс на почту настраивается стандартными функциями Settings->Messages->Recieve At -> Add Email 
далее зайти на почту, распарсить письмо и получить код. 
Правда не уверен, все ли смс будут перенаправлены на почту, и сколько времени займет пересылка и доставка на почту, т.к. время жизни смс кода ограничено 120 сек.